# Getting File or full path from Content URI returned on OnActivityResult

Tags: android

I want the user to select any file type, I use the following code to do so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*"); // TODO filter types
startActivityForResult(intent, CONVERSATION_ATTACHMENT_REQ_CODE);
```

However, on `onActivityResult` I try to get the file path using `data.getDataString` but I get `content://` uri.
How do I get the absolute file path from this uri ?
Will I always get `content://` uri's or I need to handle different data types ?

Comment: please paste full code for better understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get the absolute file path from this uri ?

You don't, just as you do not get an absolute path on your hard drive for `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33576566/getting-file-or-full-path-from-content-uri-returned-on-onactivityresult` (the URL for this question) from the URL itself. [Neither a URL nor a `Uri` is a file](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html).

Use a `ContentResolver`, and methods like `openInputStream()`, to consume the content identified by that `Uri`.

> Will I always get content:// uri's or I need to handle different data types ?

You will get whatever the activity that the user chooses to handle your implicit `Intent` elects to return. That's supposed to be `content:` `Uri` values. It might be `file:` `Uri` values, though `ContentResolver` can handle those as well.